# Query in a key-value list field DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting make a query in a field that is list of key-value, as below.

Unfortunatelly I'm novice in DynamoDB, sorry.

My goal is get a record using a filter like:

```
Where 
TransactionParameterList.Name = "HOSTING_NR" and
TransactionParameterList.OPERATION = "1234"
```

It's possible?
How?

I'm using AWS .NET SDK

Regards!

```
  "TransactionID": "657",
  "TransactionInstanceIdentifier": "919C5A0E-8786-4B86-87BF-5080E2639406",
  "TransactionParameterList": [
    {
      "Name": "HOSTING_NR",
      "Value": "1234"
    },
    {
      "Name": "OPERATION",
      "Value": "GetData"
    }
  ],
  "TransactionStepID": "1491",
  "TransactionStepInstanceIdentifier": "0B0763AB-A847-479D-8EFE-43B842F2B2EB"
}
```

Comment: What is the hash key or hash/range key that you are using for your table?  What you are describing sounds very SQL-like so it can be tricky to map into DynamoDB, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

As of now DynamoDB does not support querying list of map items.

workaround in discussion forum [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=585008#585008)